# How can I use python to find all the primitive roots of a number for which it exists?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, python

See definition of primitive roots [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n).

I have obtained the following code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40199092/15961679):

```
from math import gcd as bltin_gcd

def primRoots(modulo):
    required_set = {num for num in range(1, modulo) if bltin_gcd(num, modulo) }
    return [g for g in range(1, modulo) if required_set == {pow(g, powers, modulo)
            for powers in range(1, modulo)}]

print(primRoots(17))
```

I am not a programmer but I have python 3.6 installed on my computer. I used the above code because all I needed was to copy and paste to run it.

The problem for me is that the above doesn't return an answer if I insert a non-prime input for which a primitive root exists (such as 6).

Can any changes to the code be made so that I get an output every time I input a number of the form: $1, 2, 4, p^k, 2p^k$, where $p$ is a prime number and $k$ is an integer $\ge 1$?

Comment: I'm suddenly curious as to why someone would feel the need to rename `gcd`. Are they expecting they have to write their own in addition to the imported one?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would be better suited to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of "if gcd(modulo, num)" you should use "if gcd(modulo, num) == 1". This works for 6 on my machine, correctly predicting that mod 6 the only primitive root is 5. Your code only works on primes because the "if gcd(modulo, num)" check, without an == 1, is entirely useless and so your required set is always range(1, modulo), which happens to be the correct range if and only if your modulus is prime.

Comment: Thank, Michael. Do you also know why this doesn't return $1$ when I input $1$?

Comment: @H.H. Because range(1,1) is empty in Python. Change the return statement to range(1, modulo+1) to get it to wrok.